# reason for segmentation fault in client server chatbox program

Tags: c

i am receiving segmentation fault
here is the code

**client.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>      
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#define PORT 10001
```

**main**

```
int main(int argc ,char *argv[])
{
  struct sockaddr_in address;
  int sock = 0, valread,i=1;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  char *hello = "Hello from client";
  char buffer[1024] = {0};
  if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1)
  {
    printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
    return -1;
  }
  memset(&serv_addr,'0',sizeof(serv_addr));

  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);
  if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0) 
  {
    printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
    return -1;
  }

  if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) == -1)
  {
    printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
    return -1;
  }
  send(sock , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 );
  //printf("Hello message sent\n");
  valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024);
  printf("%d\t %s \n",i,buffer);

  **here i am getting segmentation fault**
  while(1)
  {
    valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024);
    printf("%d\t %s \n",i,buffer);
    scanf("%s",hello);
    send(sock , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 );

    i++;
    if(strcmp(buffer,"bye")==1)
    {
      break;
    }

  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `memset(&serv_addr,'0',sizeof(serv_addr))` doesn't set the memory to zeroes, instead all bytes will have the value `48` (assuming [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii) encoding). Perhaps you meant `memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr))`?

Comment: `char *hello = "Hello from client";` => `char hello[] = "Hello from client";`

Comment: `scanf("%s",hello);` is attempting to write to a *string literal* which is read-only.

Comment: `char hello[1024] = "Hello from client";` and restrict the input length too.

Comment: 'valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024);' and then ignoring 'valread'.  You must correctly and completely handle the results returned by system calls, especially recv().

Comment: 'printf("%d\t %s \n",i,buffer);' printf("%s.."..) on a char array that is not guaranteed NUL terminated, (1024 chars may be received).

Comment: 'if(strcmp(buffer,"bye")==1)' assumes that a complete C string wil be received by a single call to recv().

Comment: ''printf("%d\t %s \n",i,buffer);' printf("%s.."..)' will output extra data, repeated from previos recv() calls, if recv() loads fewer bytes than its previous call, (NUL terminator/recv result misuse).

Answer (score 2):

```
char *hello = "Hello from client";
```

is okay *until* you use `scanf` to write to `hello`. As `hello` is declared as a pointer to literal, it is *read only*.

Leave your `hello` message alone, and declare a bigger buffer (in case you have something longer to tell):

```
char answer[100];
```

and scan using limit:

```
scanf("%99s",answer);
```

Aside: `strcmp` returns 0 when matches. So comparing to `"bye"` won't work as you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You have a pointer to a string literal:

```
char *hello = "Hello from client";
```

Then you use this pointer for `scanf`:

```
scanf("%s",hello);
```

String literals mustn't be modified.

You can either solve this by using an array instead as suggested in the comments:

```
char hello[] = "Hello from client";
```

or even better with specifying an apropriate size:

```
#define MY_BUFFER_SIZE 500
char hello[MY_BUFFER_SIZE] = "Hello from client";
```

Or you could also use dynamic memory allocation as well.

In any case you should be aware that your `scanf` is not limited in size.